# What is the term for a contrasting typeface in a design?

Tags: typography

Many designs use one typeface for body text and another, contrasting typeface for headings. Is there an "official" term typographers use for the contrasting typeface in a design?

Comment: I call it using "contrasting typefaces"

Answer (score 2):

In their blog, FontShop [call it](http://blog.fontshop.com/category/great-pairs/) pairing.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the word I'm looking for. Paring is the art of finding two typefaces that work well together. I'm looking for the best term to describe only one typeface of such a pair.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a specific term other than perhaps juxtaposition. But that's not directly related to typefaces. Juxtaposition is a common concept in design.